# Trouble creating relationships using omniauth in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth

Alright so this is another try at asking my question. I did rather poorly the first time. I have a relationship set up in my models so that users have many submissions and submissions belong to a user. I have a reference column in my submissions table that references :user and an index:

```
add_index :submissions, :user_id
```

I am using omniauth so that people can sign in with twitter. I simply want to be able to have a signed-in user be able to submit a submission and then have rails understand that there is a relationship between the current_user and the submissions they just wrote. Problem is I can't seem to store current_user in an instance variable like so:

```
@user = current_user
```

which I would like to use in my submissions controller (create) like so:

```
@user = current_user
@submission = @user.submissions.create(params[:submission])
```

I need this so that I could have a user create a submission on views/submissions/index.html.rb page and rails would understand the relation. Thank you so much for looking at this. Also I apologize in advance if I just missed something really obvious or that is common knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your post does not really contain a question or did I miss something? What seems strange to me is that you want to assign `@user = current_user`. There is no need to do so, current_user should be a user anyway, therefore you could just write `@submission = current_user.submissions.create(params[:submission])`.

Maybe you can edit your post and provide more details on your helper methods (current_user), the error message you get with the code above. What do you get if you add `Rails.logger.info current_user` (or current_user.name if you have this field)?

If you want you can follow the link in my profile here on Stack Overflow, I have a couple of Rails tutorials there, including one with Omniauth.

Comment: Thanks this helped. I actually figured out most of the answer but StackOverflow wouldn't let me post it because it hadn't quite been 24hours yet. I'll definitely check out your tutorials, thanks!